# Unable to obtain linear distance matrix

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

I am using QGIS 2.6 (Brighton) and when doing a distance matrix, the output csv file appears blank. Is it possible that somehow the shapefile I am using is corrupted?Has anyone please got any hints or ideas to solve this issue?

The shapefile seems to be working well when using the attribute table! (i.e.: selecting points based on the existing fields, etc).

Comment: How many points are we talking about? Are you giving the tool sufficient time to run (ie, do you get a completed indicator)?

Comment: Please add the exact steps that you used.